# Does NLTK provide the possibility to replace numbers by English words?

Tags: python, nltk

Does Pythons NLTK provide a function to replace numbers within a text by their English name?

For example:

```
You had 1 job. -> You had one job.
42 is the answer. -> Fourty-two is the answer.
3.14 is almost pi -> Three point one four is almost pi.
```

(I don't care about capitalization).

Comment: I hope I did not make any mistake within the examples (English is not my mother tongue).

Answer (score 0):

No. NLTK does not provide a number to English generator (at least, not yet).

But here's one that can deal with integers from 1-1,000,000,000: [Numbernator](http://pastebin.com/WwFCjYtt), also there are many other alternatives, see http://pastebin.com/WwFCjYtt